# Confusion performing 2 .finds() after cloning a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hi all I have the following code as seen below whch adds a new row consisting of a text field and radio button, I have written the JS to add a new row, and I use a .find() to append the new input field with a blank value. I am new to JS and want to perform another .find() when cloning to add a value to the radio input, could someone show me how to do so please.

```
<div id='1'>
        <div class="template">
            <div>
                <label class="right inline">Response:</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="responseText[]" value="" maxlength="400" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="responseRadio[]" value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" name="addNewRow" value="Add Row" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS to add new row:

```
var $template = $('.template');
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    $template.clone().insertAfter($template).find("input:text").val("");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the cloned template and use any method you like on it before inserting it back:

```
var $template = $('.template');
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    var $elem = $template.clone();
    $elem.find("input:text").val("");
    $elem.find("input:radio").val("whatever");
    $elem.insertAfter($template);
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SWCPD/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this -

```
var $clone = $template.clone();
$clone.find("input:text").val("");
$template.after($clone);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $clonedNode = $template.clone();
$clonedNode.find('input:text').val('');
$clonedNode.find('input:radio').attr('checked', 'checked');
$template.insertAfter($clonedNode);
```

is to set the radiobutton to checked.

Comment: I want to set a vlaue of the button would I just use value and then the value that I wanted to use?

Comment: yes, then you try it with $clonedNode.find('input:radio').val('something');